# Having a reference to a property, Is there a way to grab a reference to the encompassing object?

Tags: c#, object, properties

I have extended the `Label` class as follows:

```
public class MyLabel: Label {
    public Button btn;
    public string mydata;
}
```

In my main program, I instantiated a new instance:

```
MyLabel lbl = new MyLabel();
lbl.mydata = "some data here";
lbl.btn = new Button();
lbl.btn.Click += new EventHandler(button_pressed);

this.Controls.Add(lbl); // Adds the label to the form
this.Controls.Add(lbl.btn); // Adds the button to the form
```

And I created a method to handle the button click event:

```
void button_pressed(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
     Button btn = (Button)sender;
     //Now I have an access to the property within MyLabel instance.
     // but how can I access the parent object?
     // I need to access the sibling property [mydata] string from here

     btn.Siblings["mydata"] = "some other thing" ;  //Something like this

     MyLabel lbl = btn.ParentObject();   //Or something like this
     lbl.mydata = "Some other thing";

}
```

Comment: You should write an extended button class which will keep a reference to the parent label class

Comment: Why don't you write an UserControl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like *WinForms*, in which case either a *UserControl* or extending `Button` class might be a good way to go - just maintain a reference to the parent (a bit more complicated with *UserControl*, you'd need to define the click event on that control, otherwise you're back to "square 1") I like the `Tag` property solution as well, although there is an additional cast, and no guarantee of type safety (since `Tag` is an `object`, it can be anything by the time you try to access it).

However, let's say you're looking for a more general solution; let's also say that the class in question is `sealed`, has no `Tag` or similar purpose property, and a `Controls` collection is not available (or looping through it is not desirable for performance reasons). To my best knowledge, you can't determine parent object; but you can easily provide your own "Controls" style dictionary, mapping the `Button` to the parent:

```
public class MyLabel: Label {
    public static Dictionary<Button, MyLabel> ParentMap = new Dictionary<Button, MyLabel>();

    public Button btn;
    public string mydata;

    public void AddToParentMap() => ParentMap[btn] = this;
}
```

When you're creating an instance of `MyLabel`, just call the `AddToParentMap()` function (can't be done in `constructor`, because `this` pointer is not available until the object is created):

```
MyLabel lbl = new MyLabel();
lbl.AddToParentMap();
```

You can then just look it up, fast and easy, in your click event:

```
void button_pressed(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    var label = MyLabel.ParentMap[btn];

    //...
    //Your code...
}
```

Unlike the `Tag` solution, type safety is guaranteed - you always know you're accessing a `MyLabel` object.

Comment: You have Covered all of my concerns in one post

Answer (score 0):

You can't access it through button instance but what you can do is to get `MyLabel` from `Controls` collection:

```
var lbl = this.Controls.OfType<MyLabel>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.btn == btn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Tag` property.

```
lbl.btn = new Button();
lbl.btn.Tag = lbl;
```

And then when you need it:

```
Button btn = (Button)sender;
Label lbl = (MyLabel)btn.Tag;
```

Comment: `Label lbl = (MyLabel)btn.Tag;` can throw `InvalidCastException`, since there is no way to guarantee that `Tag` stayed unchanged, as it is a general use property, of type `object`. Works in this case as a "quick fix", but not a great approach, imho.